# Does solr 4.7.2 supports duplicate records aftrer merging of index

Tags: java, apache, solr

I read somewhere that in solr if we merge two different index than there is no duplicate values ie for a unique key there will be only one record. But while using solr 4.7.2 i merged two index using the command 
[solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler)
and I found that the duplicate records are present.

Can anyone explain it please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you read that - the documentation is pretty clear that you should not merge indexes with duplicate values for the unique key as it will result in duplicates in the resulting index:

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MergingSolrIndexes

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Merging+Indexes

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Duplicate-docs-when-merging-indices-td1262043.html